# moving divs not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a total of 3 divs. **One div appears always but remaining two divs will appear when mouse enters into div1**. Here is a demo using jQuery.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gangaec/zs7jgf00/) using jQuery**

But **it's not working** properly. **When mouse enters/leaves before animation completion giving wrong functionality**. So I tried with CSS3, but animation not working properly. Demo using CSS.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gangaec/n1x41yh1/) using CSS**

**Here is code:**

**Html**:

```
<div class='holder'>
    <div class="menu" id="m1"></div>
    <div class="menu" id="m2"></div>
    <div class="menu" id="m3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
    .menu {
            top:10px;
            margin: 0;
            padding:0px;
            width: 40px;
            height:40px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #34495e;
            transition: 1s;
            position: absolute;
        }

        #m1 {
            z-index: 1000;
        }

        #m2, #m3 {
            z-index: 1;
        }


        .menu:hover {
            background-color: #3498db;
        }

        .menu:hover ~ div:nth-child(3n), .menu:hover ~ div:nth-child(2n){
            position:relative;
            left: 50px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

**How to solve the probem? How can I move the divs with proper animation and mouse events?**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a calculation to remove the amount of margin you added, just set it back to 0.

This uses the jQuery method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#m2').hide();
   $('#m3').hide();

   $('#m1').one('mouseenter', function() {
     $('#m2').show();

     //$('#m2').addClass('show');
     $('#m2').animate({

       'marginLeft': "+=45px" //moves right
     });
     $('#m3').show();

     //$('#m2').addClass('show');
     $('#m3').animate({

       'marginLeft': "+=90px" //moves right
     });
   });

   $('.holder').mouseleave(function() {
     $('#m3').animate({

       'marginLeft': "0px" // sets margin back to 0
     });
     $('#m2').animate({

       'marginLeft': "0px" // sets margin back to 0
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
.menu {
   top: 10px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #34495e;
   transition: 1s;
   position: absolute;
 }
 #m1 {
   z-index: 1000;
 }
 #m2,
 #m3 {
   z-index: 1;
 }
 .holder {
   display: block;
 }
 #m1:hover {
   background-color: #3498db;
 }
 .show {
   transition: 1s;
   position: relative;
   background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='holder'>
  <div class="menu" id="m1"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="m2"></div>
  <div class="menu" id="m3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to move #m2 and #m3 only once. From second time onwards they shouldn't go forwad.

Comment: yes, I think because of `+` in `marginLeft': "+=45px"`